# JS logic for src in a img-tag

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm fetching data, text and imageUrl from an API. In the case there are no imageUrl returned I want to display a image from my assets folder instead.

Can I write the logic inside the img-tag and if so how? or do I have to write some function outside?

This is how to code looks now:

```js
profiles.forEach((profile) => {
        expertiseContainer.innerHTML += `
        <div >
            <img src="${ profile.imgUrl }" alt="Profile image">
            <h2>${ profile.name }</h2>
        </div>
        `
    })
```

Comment: I have to assume you *meant* "assets" folder? This is, of course, irrelevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is below, using a conditional operator within the template-string:

```js
profiles.forEach((profile) => {
        expertiseContainer.innerHTML += `
        <div >
            <img src="${ profile.imgUrl ? profile.imgUrl : 'assets/default.png' }" alt="Profile image">
            <h2>${ profile.name }</h2>
        </div>
        `
    })
```